# YouTube Playlist Annoyances (Sorting, etc)

Tags: youtube, sorting, youtube-playlist

If I am viewing a video, and I wish to add it to a playlist of mine, I click on the Add to Playlist button. (I bet you're going, "No, *duh*.")

The problem with this is:

- I have 18 playlists and counting.

  - If I use my mouse scroll wheel, I just end up going past the playlist I want.
  - The playlist window is *way* too small.
  - If I eventually get 100 playlists, it will be a real pain trying to find my playlist, and actually scrolling to it, even if I know where it is.
- They are sorted in *chronological* order, which makes them hard to find.

Is there any way I can mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite frustrated for this problem too. The only solution I found was to code a Greasemonkey (Firefox add-on) script to manipulate the YouTube interface.

It also works on Chrome. Check this out: [Userscript source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20120727000524/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/123272).

Comment: @Laurel , the link was updated to point to the archived version on archive.org. Due to the changes done to YouTube, web browsers and the related extensions, it's unlikely that the link will be helpful nowadays. Situations like this make us require that **posts** be self-contained.

Comment: @Rubén Sure, the userscript may be broken but I don't understand what that has to do with the question, which does explain in detail what the default behavior is and what it's looking for. In fact, if you go to YouTube right now, you'll see that playlists *still* aren't sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I'm sorry was not talking about the question. I should be using *questions and answers* or even better, **posts**. (comment edited).